# Confused with NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-activity, onclicklistener

I know that i am probably missing something simple but i am getting this error when i try to load my second activity and i have no idea why, I understand (Or iv'e been told) That it happens when your code doesn't point to anything, But iv'e checked it and it points to the correct location.

**ResultText**

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ResultText extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addListenerOnButton(); 
               //Points /\

}




public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnHome);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            //Points /\
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

    String result=getIntent().getStringExtra("resultText");
    setContentView(R.layout.result_text);
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
       tv.setTextSize(20);

       String str=result;
       tv.setText(str);
       setContentView(tv);
}

}
```

If you require any more of the files feel free to ask.

Sorry if its a noob question and thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call  `setContentView(R.layout.result_text);` before calling `addListenerOnButton();`

Like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_text);
    addListenerOnButton(); 

}
```

Comment: That makes it load but it doesn't show the button that is on the activity?

Comment: Where do i need to add an exception to? (I'm still quite new to eclipse)

Comment: write your entire code of `addListenerOnButton();` in try catch block. I think your Intent is null. If you dont want to add try-catch block , comment all lines from `String result=getIntent().getStringExtra("resultText");`

Comment: "Comment all lines from `String result=getIntent().getStringExtra("resultText");` You mean show the code from my main activity that gives that information?

Comment: check my edited answer. I have commented those lines. Now you will be able to see your button.

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the text and button again, This means that i have caused a null transfer of the data? do you have any experience in moving scan results from one activity to another?

Comment: yes. your intent was null. and what you want exactly ?

Comment: Asked the question before but no response so i had to trial until it didn't crash :P
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051306/using-zxing-result-on-multiple-activities

Comment: sorry I dont have any idea related to QR scan.